# Administrator access denied to CiviMail

Tags: civimail

I've mostly successfully migrated CiviCRM and Drupal to a new host and updated the software. I'm now running CiviCRM 5.24.5 under Drupal 7.70.  I am logged in as an administrator, and I can access pretty much everything except I'm having an issue with CiviMail. If I select "New Mailing" from the Mailings menu, I get an Access Denied message. I also get it if I try to reuse a previously sent mailing (these were all sent before the migration and upgrades).

I've looked at the user permissions in Drupal for CiviCRM and don't see any that seem specifically relevant to the mailings, and I have enabled permissions for everything for administrators anyway. I do not appear to be denied access to any other administrative function in CiviCRM - just this one in CiviMail.

How to I specifically enable permission to access the CiviMail New Mailings page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Access Denied" is typically a Drupal-level permissions issue, but can sometimes be misleading (something in the civicrm drupal module may be throwing a permission denied call). The first thing would definitely be to clear the menu caches, which is where some level of permissions may be happening. Another thing to consider is if you set up with a temporary domain and then switched it, that sometimes leaves temporary problems.

Comment: That was it. I had set up a temporary domain as the prototype before I made the DNS change to make the new site the default. I'd missed a stale URL in the CiviCRM settings. Thanks for the pointer!